# Trying to make a drop down menu using javascript and it is not working?

Tags: javascript, menu

I am really new at javascript but as far as I can tell, the code that I have here should be working.  No errors come up when I view in the console(nothing comes up for that matter) and all that appears on the website is the button that doesn't do anything and the list items already appearing on the page

```
<html>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="accordion">Collections</button>
    <ul class="dropDown">
      <li><p>Mojica Lookbook</p></li>
      <li><p>Andrade Editorial</p></li>
      <li><p>Bell Videos</p></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="stores.html">Stores</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="mojica_lookbook/mojica_credits.png" class="credits">
  </li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
 </body>

    <script>

      var dropDown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropDown");
      var i = 0;

      for(i = 0; i < dropDown.length; i++) {
         dropDown[i].onclick = function(){
           this.classList.toggle("active");
           this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
       }
       }
       </script>

     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to use the element passed into the callback for the onclick.  Instead of using the 'this' keyword within the callback try this:

```
for(i = 0; i < dropDown.length; i++) {
  dropDown[i].onclick = function(e){
    e.target.classList.toggle("active");
    e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

There are a few examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp).  As for the button you have not mapped a click event, so that will as you explain do nothing.